# HTMLDocument Iterator skipping a tags

Tags: java, iterator, dom

I'm using an HTMLDocument Iterator to try and iterate over all of the a tags in an HTMLDocument. However, the iterator seems to be skipping over a tags that are nested inside p tags. For example:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <a href = "somesite"> some site </a>
        <p>
            <a href = "someothersite"> some other site </a>
        </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

The iterator will get the first a tag (somesite), but it won't go to the a tag within the p tags (someothersite).

Here's the code:

```
private void getLinks() throws MalformedURLException {
    HTMLDocument.Iterator it = content.getIterator(HTML.Tag.A);           
    it.next();
        while(it.isValid()) {
            // Do something
            it.next();
        }
}
```

Can anybody suggest why?

Comment: Ah - turns out it was that first it.next() before entering the loop..

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the `isValid()` check breaks your loop. Try if the iterator hits the second anchor tag without that check.

Comment: That's the problem - it is breaking the loop, but It shouldn't as there are more a tags left in the document..